# 3d borehole view for ArcScene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, line, borehole

I am trying to make a 3D Representation on the well from the following data. I cnat put it in a table work from there and use python. Just not sure the math. Anyone Help I do have the starting coordinates for the Borehole.

LOG DEPTH                 The depth recorded on the field logs for the borehole.
TRUE DEPTH                The true vertical depth corresponding to the above depth.    Corrected from the
start of the analysis.
HOLE TILT AND AZIMUTH     The sampled borehole orientation.
AXIAL COORDINATES         The coordinates North and East from the target origin.
POLAR COORDINATES         The polar or radial coordinates of the borehole.
N.B. The reference point for all bearing angles on this listing is given at the top of each sheet.

All interpretations are opinions based on inferences from electrical or other measurements and we cannot,
and do not, guarantee the accuracy or correctness of any interpretations, and we shall not, except in the
case of gross or wilful negligence on our part, be liable or responsible for any loss, costs, damages or
expenses incurred or sustained by anyone resulting from any interpretation made by any of our officers,
agents or employees. These interpretations are also subject to our general terms and conditions as set out
in our current price schedule.

All co-ordinates with respect to True North

```
    DEPT       TDEP          VTLT    VAZT        AXLN       AXLE     BBRG       BRAD
~ASCII Log Data
   1600.000    1600.00       0.2     100.8       0.00       0.01      101       0.01
   1625.000    1625.00       0.3     141.9      -0.03       0.04      128       0.05
   1650.000    1650.00       0.2     164.2      -0.05       0.05      138       0.07
   1675.000    1675.00       0.2     341.4      -0.03       0.04      130       0.05
   1700.000    1700.00       0.1     327.9      -0.02       0.03      122       0.03
   1725.000    1725.00       0.2     284.2      -0.01       0.02      121       0.02
   1750.000    1750.00       0.2     284.3       0.00      -0.04      275       0.04
   1775.000    1775.00       0.2     323.7       0.06      -0.08      308       0.11
   1800.000    1800.00       0.2     359.7       0.12      -0.08      326       0.15
   1825.000    1825.00       0.2       0.6       0.20      -0.08      338       0.21
   1850.000    1850.00       0.2     356.3       0.25      -0.08      342       0.27
   1875.000    1875.00       0.2     355.8       0.33      -0.09      345       0.34
   1900.000    1900.00       0.2     354.2       0.41      -0.10      347       0.42
   1925.000    1925.00       0.3     350.7       0.50      -0.11      348       0.51
   1950.000    1950.00       0.2     343.3       0.58      -0.13      347       0.60
   1975.000    1975.00       0.3     341.9       0.68      -0.17      346       0.70
   2000.000    2000.00       0.3     347.9       0.80      -0.19      347       0.83
   2025.000    2025.00       0.3     353.7       0.93      -0.20      348       0.95
   2050.000    2050.00       0.3     348.7       1.03      -0.22      348       1.06
   2075.000    2075.00       0.3       7.6       1.13      -0.21      349       1.15
   2100.000    2100.00       0.3     351.3       1.23      -0.23      349       1.25
   2125.000    2125.00       0.3     344.1       1.35      -0.26      349       1.38
   2150.000    2150.00       0.3     333.3       1.45      -0.31      348       1.48
   2175.000    2175.00       0.3     334.4       1.54      -0.35      347       1.58
   2200.000    2199.99       0.3     336.0       1.66      -0.41      346       1.71
   2225.000    2224.99       0.4     340.1       1.81      -0.46      346       1.86
   2250.000    2249.99       0.4     346.3       1.99      -0.50      346       2.05
   2275.000    2274.99       0.4     333.4       2.16      -0.58      345       2.23
   2300.000    2299.99       0.5     330.6       2.35      -0.70      343       2.45
   2325.000    2324.99       0.6     336.0       2.58      -0.80      343       2.70
   2350.000    2349.99       0.7     339.5       2.85      -0.90      343       2.98
   2375.000    2374.99       0.6     337.2       3.09      -1.00      342       3.25
   2400.000    2399.99       0.7     337.4       3.37      -1.12      342       3.55
   2425.000    2424.98       0.7     340.2       3.65      -1.22      342       3.85
   2450.000    2449.98       0.8     342.8       3.97      -1.32      342       4.18
   2475.000    2474.98       0.8     343.2       4.29      -1.41      342       4.52
   2500.000    2499.98       0.7     341.8       4.60      -1.51      342       4.84
   2525.000    2524.98       0.7     340.8       4.90      -1.62      342       5.16
   2550.000    2549.97       0.7     340.0       5.20      -1.73      342       5.48
   2575.000    2574.97       0.8     337.1       5.51      -1.86      341       5.82
   2600.000    2599.97       0.8     338.4       5.83      -1.99      341       6.16
   2625.000    2624.97       0.8     338.4       6.14      -2.11      341       6.49
   2650.000    2649.96       0.8     340.9       6.48      -2.23      341       6.85
   2675.000    2674.96       0.8     335.6       6.79      -2.37      341       7.20
   2700.000    2699.96       0.8     337.8       7.11      -2.50      341       7.53
   2725.000    2724.96       0.8     336.7       7.42      -2.63      340       7.87
   2750.000    2749.95       0.8     334.0       7.72      -2.78      340       8.21
   2775.000    2774.95       0.9     335.9       8.08      -2.94      340       8.59
   2800.000    2799.95       0.9     338.6       8.44      -3.08      340       8.99
   2825.000    2824.95       0.8     333.7       8.77      -3.24      340       9.35
   2850.000    2849.94       0.8     335.8       9.10      -3.39      340       9.72
   2875.000    2874.94       0.8     334.1       9.43      -3.55      339      10.08
   2900.000    2899.94       0.8     334.1       9.76      -3.71      339      10.44
   2925.000    2924.93       0.8     331.3      10.07      -3.88      339      10.80
   2950.000    2949.93       0.8     332.0      10.38      -4.05      339      11.14
   2975.000    2974.93       0.8     328.4      10.67      -4.23      338      11.48
   3000.000    2999.93       0.8     327.9      10.96      -4.41      338      11.81
   3025.000    3024.93       0.8     328.1      11.25      -4.59      338      12.15
   3050.000    3049.92       0.8     329.2      11.54      -4.76      338      12.48
   3075.000    3074.92       0.8     328.7      11.83      -4.94      337      12.82
   3100.000    3099.92       0.7     327.6      12.11      -5.11      337      13.14
   3125.000    3124.92       0.8     328.3      12.39      -5.28      337      13.47
   3150.000    3149.91       0.8     327.0      12.69      -5.48      337      13.82
   3175.000    3174.91       0.8     330.4      12.99      -5.65      336      14.17
   3200.000    3199.91       0.8     329.4      13.31      -5.84      336      14.54
   3225.000    3224.91       0.8     329.7      13.62      -6.02      336      14.89
   3250.000    3249.90       0.8     331.5      13.95      -6.20      336      15.26
   3275.000    3274.90       0.9     333.3      14.28      -6.36      336      15.63
   3300.000    3299.90       0.8     337.1      14.59      -6.50      336      15.97
   3325.000    3324.90       0.8     339.6      14.91      -6.61      336      16.31
   3350.000    3349.89       0.8     339.4      15.23      -6.73      336      16.65
   3375.000    3374.89       0.7     342.4      15.53      -6.83      336      16.96
   3400.000    3399.89       0.7     345.5      15.83      -6.91      336      17.27
   3425.000    3424.89       0.8     345.4      16.15      -6.99      337      17.60
   3450.000    3449.88       0.8     351.2      16.47      -7.04      337      17.92
   3475.000    3474.88       0.8     351.2      16.82      -7.09      337      18.26
   3500.000    3499.88       0.8     351.9      17.15      -7.14      337      18.58
   3525.000    3524.88       0.8     352.5      17.52      -7.19      338      18.94
   3550.000    3549.87       0.8     355.0      17.88      -7.22      338      19.28
   3575.000    3574.87       0.8     353.9      18.25      -7.26      338      19.64
   3600.000    3599.87       0.9     356.1      18.64      -7.28      339      20.01
   3625.000    3624.87       0.9     355.7      19.03      -7.31      339      20.39
   3650.000    3649.86       1.0     354.4      19.47      -7.36      339      20.81
   3675.000    3674.86       1.0     353.8      19.90      -7.40      340      21.23
   3700.000    3699.85       1.0     353.9      20.33      -7.45      340      21.65
   3725.000    3724.85       1.0     355.1      20.75      -7.48      340      22.06
   3750.000    3749.85       1.0     352.3      21.17      -7.54      340      22.48
   3775.000    3774.84       0.9     348.8      21.55      -7.62      341      22.86
   3800.000    3799.84       0.8     340.2      21.90      -7.74      341      23.23
   3825.000    3824.84       0.8     340.5      22.24      -7.86      341      23.59
   3850.000    3849.84       0.8     344.0      22.57      -7.96      341      23.93
   3875.000    3874.83       0.8     346.3      22.91      -8.04      341      24.28
   3900.000    3899.83       0.8     347.2      23.26      -8.12      341      24.63
   3925.000    3924.83       0.8     349.5      23.60      -8.18      341      24.98
   3950.000    3949.83       0.8     345.9      23.94      -8.27      341      25.33
   3975.000    3974.82       0.8     348.7      24.27      -8.33      341      25.66
   4000.000    3999.82       0.8     347.6      24.59      -8.40      341      25.99
   4025.000    4024.82       0.8     349.6      24.94      -8.47      341      26.34
   4050.000    4049.82       0.8     348.0      25.29      -8.54      341      26.69
   4075.000    4074.81       0.9     346.7      25.66      -8.63      341      27.07
   4100.000    4099.81       0.8     344.6      26.01      -8.72      341      27.43
   4125.000    4124.81       0.9     343.6      26.36      -8.83      341      27.80
   4150.000    4149.81       0.8     342.4      26.72      -8.94      342      28.17
   4175.000    4174.80       0.9     341.2      27.08      -9.06      341      28.55
   4200.000    4199.80       0.9     340.4      27.45      -9.19      341      28.95
   4225.000    4224.80       0.9     341.3      27.84      -9.33      341      29.36
   4250.000    4249.79       0.9     343.3      28.20      -9.43      342      29.74
   4275.000    4274.79       0.8     343.3      28.55      -9.54      342      30.10
   4300.000    4299.79       0.9     340.7      28.90      -9.66      342      30.48
   4325.000    4324.78       0.9     337.4      29.27      -9.82      341      30.87
   4350.000    4349.78       0.9     337.6      29.64      -9.97      341      31.27
   4375.000    4374.78       0.9     336.7      30.02     -10.13      341      31.68
   4400.000    4399.77       0.9     329.6      30.37     -10.33      341      32.08
   4425.000    4424.77       1.0     331.8      30.73     -10.53      341      32.49
   4450.000    4449.77       0.9     330.9      31.08     -10.72      341      32.88
   4475.000    4474.77       0.9     332.7      31.42     -10.90      341      33.26
   4500.000    4499.76       0.9     333.0      31.75     -11.07      341      33.63
   4525.000    4524.76       0.8     331.9      32.08     -11.24      341      33.99
   4550.000    4549.76       0.8     332.6      32.38     -11.40      341      34.33
   4575.000    4574.75       0.7     333.6      32.66     -11.54      341      34.64
   4600.000    4599.75       0.7     334.4      32.93     -11.67      340      34.94
   4625.000    4624.75       0.6     333.6      33.16     -11.78      340      35.20
   4650.000    4649.75       0.6     332.7      33.40     -11.90      340      35.46
   4675.000    4674.75       0.6     333.2      33.64     -12.02      340      35.72
   4700.000    4699.75       0.5     333.6      33.85     -12.13      340      35.96
   4725.000    4724.75       0.6     333.5      34.08     -12.24      340      36.21
   4750.000    4749.75       0.5     332.1      34.28     -12.35      340      36.44
   4775.000    4774.74       0.5     329.7      34.47     -12.46      340      36.65
   4800.000    4799.74       0.5     331.6      34.66     -12.56      340      36.87
   4825.000    4824.74       0.5     333.0      34.87     -12.67      340      37.10
   4850.000    4849.74       0.6     331.8      35.08     -12.78      340      37.33
   4875.000    4874.74       0.6     331.6      35.29     -12.90      340      37.58
   4900.000    4899.74       0.6     330.6      35.50     -13.02      340      37.81
   4925.000    4924.74       0.6     330.7      35.73     -13.14      340      38.07
   4950.000    4949.74       0.5     330.7      35.93     -13.26      340      38.30
   4975.000    4974.74       0.5     328.3      36.12     -13.37      340      38.52
   5000.000    4999.73       0.5     327.0      36.31     -13.49      340      38.73
   5025.000    5024.73       0.5     328.8      36.49     -13.61      340      38.95
   5050.000    5049.73       0.6     324.3      36.69     -13.75      339      39.18
   5075.000    5074.73       0.6     326.0      36.89     -13.88      339      39.42
   5100.000    5099.73       0.5     326.3      37.08     -14.01      339      39.64
   5125.000    5124.73       0.5     324.9      37.27     -14.14      339      39.87
   5150.000    5149.73       0.6     322.2      37.47     -14.29      339      40.10
   5175.000    5174.73       0.6     320.6      37.66     -14.45      339      40.33
   5200.000    5199.73       0.5     322.2      37.84     -14.60      339      40.56
   5225.000    5224.72       0.5     321.5      38.02     -14.74      339      40.78
   5250.000    5249.72       0.6     319.1      38.21     -14.90      339      41.01
   5275.000    5274.72       0.7     320.2      38.43     -15.08      339      41.28
   5300.000    5299.72       0.7     315.4      38.64     -15.30      338      41.56
   5325.000    5324.72       0.8     319.4      38.91     -15.53      338      41.90
   5350.000    5349.71       0.9     318.4      39.19     -15.78      338      42.25
   5375.000    5374.71       1.0     327.2      39.56     -16.01      338      42.68
   5400.000    5399.71       1.1     334.9      40.01     -16.22      338      43.17
   5425.000    5424.70       1.4     328.5      40.52     -16.53      338      43.76
   5450.000    5449.68       2.1     326.1      41.27     -17.04      338      44.65
   5475.000    5474.65       3.0     325.9      42.32     -17.75      337      45.90
   5500.000    5499.58       4.1     325.0      43.78     -18.77      337      47.64
   5525.000    5524.47       5.4     324.4      45.68     -20.13      336      49.92
   5550.000    5549.31       6.7     324.1      48.02     -21.83      336      52.74
   5575.000    5574.04       8.3     323.6      50.93     -23.98      335      56.29
   5600.000    5598.71       9.4     323.2      54.20     -26.42      334      60.30
   5625.000    5623.32      10.1     322.3      57.64     -29.09      333      64.56
   5650.000    5647.90      10.6     322.2      61.26     -31.89      333      69.07
   5675.000    5672.44      11.0     322.1      65.01     -34.81      332      73.75
   5700.000    5696.94      11.5     322.3      68.99     -37.89      331      78.71
   5725.000    5721.44      11.5     322.0      72.90     -40.95      331      83.62
   5750.000    5745.92      11.6     321.8      76.85     -44.06      330      88.58
   5775.000    5770.42      11.6     322.0      80.79     -47.14      330      93.54
   5800.000    5794.90      11.7     322.0      84.78     -50.26      329      98.56
   5825.000    5819.36      11.8     321.6      88.84     -53.48      329     103.70
   5850.000    5843.79      12.3     321.9      93.02     -56.75      329     108.97
   5875.000    5868.21      12.4     321.7      97.21     -60.06      328     114.27
   5900.000    5892.62      12.5     321.9     101.47     -63.40      328     119.64
   5925.000    5917.02      12.6     321.9     105.73     -66.75      328     125.04
   5950.000    5941.41      12.6     321.3     110.03     -70.19      327     130.51
   5975.000    5965.78      12.9     321.1     114.37     -73.68      327     136.05
   6000.000    5990.15      12.9     320.4     118.67     -77.24      327     141.59
   6025.000    6014.44      13.8     320.9     123.27     -80.97      327     147.48
   6050.000    6038.65      14.4     320.6     128.07     -84.91      326     153.66
   6075.000    6062.77      15.2     319.9     133.14     -89.17      326     160.24
   6100.000    6086.86      15.5     319.6     138.21     -93.49      326     166.86
   6125.000    6110.93      15.7     319.0     143.31     -97.93      326     173.58
   6150.000    6134.97      15.9     318.7     148.45    -102.44      325     180.37
   6175.000    6158.97      16.3     318.9     153.72    -107.03      325     187.31
   6200.000    6182.94      16.5     319.2     159.14    -111.71      325     194.43
   6225.000    6206.93      16.3     319.3     164.44    -116.27      325     201.39
   6250.000    6230.97      16.0     319.4     169.67    -120.74      325     208.24
   6275.000    6255.01      15.9     319.5     174.86    -125.18      324     215.05
   6300.000    6279.06      15.9     319.4     180.06    -129.62      324     221.86
   6325.000    6303.12      15.7     319.2     185.21    -134.08      324     228.65
   6350.000    6327.25      15.2     319.0     190.14    -138.36      324     235.15
   6375.000    6351.43      14.7     319.5     194.95    -142.48      324     241.46
   6400.000    6375.67      14.2     319.7     199.62    -146.44      324     247.58
   6425.000    6399.95      13.8     319.8     204.16    -150.27      324     253.50
   6450.000    6424.27      13.3     320.1     208.62    -154.00      324     259.30
```

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't sorted this yet and are after a deviated linetrace I would use your bore collar XYZ to calculate downhole points using fields such as:

Borehole_id, DH.X = Collar.X + AXLE, DH.Y = Collar.Y + AXLN, DH.Z = Collar.Z - TDEP

Create 3D points from the table using DH.X, DH.Y, DH.Z
and then Data management > Points_to_Line breaking the lines on borehole_id (name), sorting on TDEP. That should create a 3D polyline for each borehole for you.

If you wind up getting downhole las files without the axial offsets you'll then need the trig calcs to create the DH points.

dX = Total_Depth * math.sin(math.radians(Azimuth))*math.cos(math.radians(Inclination))

dY = Total_Depth * math.cos(math.radians(Azimuth))*math.cos(math.radians(Inclination))

dZ = Total_Depth * math.sin(math.radians(Inclination))

DH_X = Easting + dX

DH_Y = Northing + dY

DH_Z = RL - dZ